# hive create table input.regex - filter out all rows starting with a char

Tags: regex, hive, create-table, hive-serde, regexserde

I want to create table in Hive

```
CREATE TABLE table (
    a     string
   ,b     string
) 
PARTITIONED BY ( pr_filename string )
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('input.regex'='reg_exp') ;
```

but source data have multiline header starting with "#"

```
# <some comment>
#
# <some other comments>
# <some other comments>
# <some other comments>
#
a,b
1,2
8,2
8,9
```

Is it possible to write *reg_exp* to filter out all rows starting with chosen character or do I have to use temporary table to deal with this header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to filter like this:

```
'input.regex'='^([^#]+),([a-zA-Z])' --first group is everything except #
```

The row will be returned anyway with NULLs, you can filter such records.

[RegexSerDe JavaDocs](https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r2.1.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/contrib/serde2/RegexSerDe.html) says: 
 In deserialization stage, **if a row does not match the regex, then all columns in the row will be NULL**. If a row matches the regex but has less than expected groups, the missing groups will be NULL. If a row matches the regex but has more than expected groups, the additional groups are just ignored

**The solution is to use intermediate table + filter rows when selecting from it.**